# Can the Square API help customize a giving interface?

Tags: square, square-connect, applepay

How can I integrate the Square API into a church website? I want to have a donation box with a dropdown menu, you can not do that with the store which is why I'm looking at if the API maybe able to help.

Comment: This question is far too broad, and is at risk of downvotes. The answer is probably "yes" but I am not sure if that is useful. I would recommend deleting it, or if you can do some research and expand the question to something that is focussed and answerable, that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Square's APIs to accept payments online, but most of this would likely be done with a developer. I'd recommend finding one as your first step!

Comment: I am a developer. I'm just asking if its worth my time or if I can not develop what I'm looking for.